# Parse .net SDK Get Object

Tags: c#, .net, parse-platform

I have been trying to return the `string` of the result but it doesn't return anything. When I do `Console.WriteLine` it shows the link.

But the line:

```
s = nzk.Get<string>("link");
```

doesn't do anything, and I don't know why.

Here's my code:

```
public string getlink(String ID)
{
    ParseClient.Initialize(new ParseClient.Configuration
    {
        ApplicationId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx5335c1fxxx0f19efxxxx06787e",
        Server = "http://api.assintates.net/parse/"
    });
    string s = "";
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseObject.GetQuery("test");
    query.GetAsync(ID).ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        ParseObject nzk = t.Result;
        Console.WriteLine(nzk.Get<string>("link"));  // this works 
        s = nzk.Get<string>("link");// this doesn't work 
    });
    return s;
}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        g_get x = new g_get();
        Console.WriteLine(x.getlink("iLQLJKPoJA")); // shows nothing since i initialized the s with ""
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

Comment: How do you consume `getlink` in your application? Can you provide some more details?

Comment: edited the code :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a little example to demonstrate your problem:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(GetString());

    Console.ReadLine();
}

private static async Task TimeConsumingTask()
{
    await Task.Run(() => System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100));
}

private static string GetString()
{
    string s = "I am empty";
    TimeConsumingTask().ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        s = "GetString was called";
    });

    return s;
}
```

Your output will be the following:

```
I am empty
```

Why? The thing to deal with is the `ContinueWith()`-function (see [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991174(v=vs.110).aspx)).
`ContinueWith` returns you the Task-object. You have to await this task and in your code you didn't await it.

So simple solution call [wait](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235606(v=vs.110).aspx) on your Task-object.

```
    string s = "";
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseObject.GetQuery("test");
    query.GetAsync(ID).ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        ParseObject nzk = t.Result;
        Console.WriteLine(nzk.Get<string>("link"));  // this works 
        s = nzk.Get<string>("link");// this doesn't work 
    }).Wait();
    return s;
```

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async) some more information about asynchronous programming in C#.

Edit: Some more information

You will see the console output because your task will be run anyway. But it will be run after you returned your string.

Comment: ahhh, thank you so much, sorry i just shifted from java so i'm still learning c#. thank you again !!